# App crashes without any memory warning in iPad1 but working in iPad3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

The app crashes when we use the following code in iPad1 but it is working well in iPad3.

```
roboObj.animationImages=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"p4Robot1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"paot4.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"4Robot5.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"pagot8.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"page4t9.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"page10.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"pabot11.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"pagt12.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"page4ot13.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"pbot2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"paot3.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"page.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"pagt15.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"page4t16.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"pagbot17.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"pa18.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"page18.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"pa18.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"pag18.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"page8.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"pagbot18.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"paot17.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"pot16.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"pt15.png"],nil];
        roboObj.animationDuration=4;
        roboObj.animationRepeatCount=1;
        [roboObj startAnimating];
```

some times i am getting a memory warning "Received memory warning. Level=1" & "Received memory warning. Level=2".

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this issue.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: does it crash on the ipad 1 during the animation running? or it doesn't even start?

Comment: Yes, it crashes on iPad 1 and 2 and not in simulator

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way of loading images while trying to repeat animation.I am not sure whether this is the exact answer you're looking for but for some extent you will get the idea.

Have a look at this article...

[UIImageView AnimationImages Memory Leak](http://iphone.sanniv.com/2009/08/25/1-uiimageview-animationimages-memory-leak-mistry-solved/)

We all know that to do animation using UIImageView, we load images in the NSArray and then set it to animationImages property of UIImageView and then call function startAnimating.
But when you try to repeat animation by loading again and again with different images using this method, you start experiencing Crash on iPhone device with status 101 at Xcode debug. Again, we all know why it crashed, just because of no more memory available for our app in the iPhone device.
But where did our memory went. Here is the answer for that. Every time when we set NSArray to animationImages, the whole data gets copied to it because animationImages is copy property of UIImageView. And if we try to again set same animationImages with some other NSArray, we try to nil it first then set with new array. But here we are wrong, when we nil this property, the real time memory decreases but the virtual memory doesn’t decrease because garbage collector is not there.
So instead nil we should call release method of this property which will force it to get freed from the virtual memory too. One more thing you should remember, don’t call release method of this property or don’t try to nil this property in dealloc method where your UIImageView’s reference is released, otherwise either you will get Bad Parameter warning or again virtual memory will not get freed.

Sample Code is also given [here](http://iphone.sanniv.com/2009/08/25/1-uiimageview-animationimages-memory-leak-mistry-solved/).

Comment: I tried this code but still my iPad get crashed when i keep on playing the same animation again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your images are too large. iPad 1 anyway does not have retina display. Downscale your images to half the size and try again.